# Convert images to Icons is giving errors

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm converting images to icons using this code:

```
import PIL.image

img = PIL.Image.open ("imagepath.png")
img.save ("iconpath.ico")
```

This is giving me an icon file as desired, but when I try to open it an error pops up:
Paint:
[image: Paint error]
Microsoft photos error:
[image: Microsoft photos error]

When I try to open other icons with the same programs they work perfectly, but it doesn't with the ones I made. Does anyone know any other way or library for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
img.save('iconpath.ico',format = 'ICO', sizes=[(32,32)])
```

You can change size to 16,16

First time I was converting image with PIL I've used this tutorial:

[Tutorial](https://www.tutorialexample.com/convert-png-to-ico-with-pillow-for-python-beginners-python-tutorial/)

Everything worked fine.

The image that is being converted has to have a 1:1 proportion, if not, when trying to open the generated icon it will cause errors.

Comment: I think I have found the error. When trying to reopen the result icon back with `PIL.Image.open`, it shows this error; `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py:306: UserWarning: Image was not the expected size
  warnings.warn("Image was not the expected size")
<PIL.IcoImagePlugin.IcoImageFile image mode=RGB size=256x238 at 0x22275E2A400>`

Comment: I think that the images have to be resized before conversion, but I don't know how to do it, I have thought of adding transparent stipes on the sides of the imagen to make the ratio be 1:1.

Comment: That is why you have `sizes=[(32,32)]`.  Yes ratio need to be 1:1 for .ico max size is 255x255. Change one line of your code for what I gave you in the answer and see if it will work.

Comment: I used the exact line you provided and the error is still the same.

Comment: That's weird. Just did it a second ago and I have exactly the same issue now as you, but if I use this converted image in Tkinter as an icon it works just fine. Perhaps that is a windows issue. no idea.

Comment: I have just done it with an image with 1:1 proportions and works good, with the same line you posted.